# C++: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, pointers

I just wrote a piece of code to merge 2 sorted arrays. The merging works fine. However when i try to print the sorted array. I get just a bunch of 1's repeated

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define G_N_ELEMENTS(arr) ((sizeof(arr))/(sizeof(arr[0])))

class mergeArray{
    public:
    int *A,*B,*C;
    mergeArray(int *A,int *B)
    {
        this->A = A;
        this->B = B;
    }
    void  mergeArrays(int sizeA,int sizeB)
    {
        int newSize = sizeA+sizeB;
        C = new int[newSize+1];
        int i=0,j=0,k=0;
        while(k<newSize)
        {
            if(*(A+i)<*(B+j))
            {
                *(C+k)=*(A+i);
                if(i<sizeA)i++;
            }
            else
            {
                *(C+k)=*(B+j);
                if(j<sizeB)j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        *(C+newSize) = -1;
    }
    void printMergeArray()
    {
        int i=0;
        while(*(C+i)!=-1)
        {
            cout<< *(C+i)<<endl;
        }
    }

};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int A[5]={1,3,5,7,9};
    int B[5]={2,4,6,8,10};
    mergeArray mm(A,B);
    int sizeA = G_N_ELEMENTS(A);
    int sizeB = G_N_ELEMENTS(B);
    mm.mergeArrays(sizeA,sizeB);
    mm.printMergeArray();
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I debugged the code using gdb. And the merge works fine and when I print using the GDB print command the merged array has correct values.

Comment: You do not increment the variable `i` in `printMergeArray`.

Comment: God damn it, Sorry for bothering.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for your preferring pointer arithmetic `*(C+i)` over indexing `C[i]`?

Comment: if this is not one of this weird "I am not allowed to use standard C++ stuff" assignments, I would strongly advise you to use std::vector

Answer (score 1):

I realize that you already have your answer from one of the comments - you are not incrementing the index in `printMergeArray`.

My motivation for this answer is to suggest some stylistic changes:

I think `while` loops of the form

```
while(k<newSize)
{
    k++;
}
```

are inferior to the form:

```
for( k = 0; k < newSize; ++k)
{
}
```

Also,

```
*(C+k)=*(A+i);
if(i<sizeA)i++;
```

can be replaced by stronger assertion.

```
assert(i < sizeA);
*(C+k)=*(A+i);
i++;
```

Similarly,

```
*(C+k)=*(B+j);
if(j<sizeB)j++;
```

can be replaced by:

```
assert(j < sizeB);
*(C+k)=*(B+j);
j++;
```